# Update product_carrier table with a CSV file

Tags: php, csv, prestashop

I realize a script to update a table prestashop -> product_carrier with a CSV. My CSV has 2 columns.

A "reference" column and a "true / false" column. When I browse the CSV and a reference is equal to 0 I insert in the table 3 lines which concerns the carrier references. My problem is that when I browse the CSV the var_dump shows me NULLs and I do not see why. Here is my code:

```
    <?php

require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.inc.php');

$dir_fichier = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/IMPORTS/STOCK_EXPRESS_FR'.'.csv';

tntProduct($dir_fichier);

function tntProduct($dir_fichier)
{
    $csv = new SplFileObject($dir_fichier);
    $csv->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
    $csv->setCsvControl(';');

    $carriersFR = [
        0 => 1,
        1 => 72,
        2 => 87
    ];

    foreach($csv as $ligne){
        echo '<pre>';
        if ($ligne[1] == 0) {
            getProductsIds($ligne[0], $carriersFR);
        }
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}

function getProductsIds($reference, $carriers)
{
    $sql = Db::getInstance()->executeS('
            SELECT p.id_product 
            FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product p
            WHERE p.reference = '.'"'.$reference.'"');

        foreach ($sql as $key => $item) {
                $productsIds[$key]['id_product'] = (int)$item['id_product'];
                $productsIds[$key]['id_carrier_reference'] = $carriers;
                $productsIds[$key]['id_shop'] = 1;  
        }

    foreach ($productsIds as $productsId) {
        $product[] = $productsId;
    }

        var_dump($product);

    return $productsIds;
}
```

it displays

[image]

Example CSV:

```
831S587 0
822 0
10601   13
61703111    0
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: edit my post. thx

Comment: No. but first column is reference and second colomn 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer here is what resort

[image]

i need this format for function setCarriers();

[image]

Comment: Not my last code does not work sorry. The CSV does not change it is separated by ";"

Comment: Hello, I managed to insert the lines in database but I would like to check if I have the right number by counting the number of result